# How to select [somename] from a table in my database

Tags: php, mysql

The code below will display John, Steve, and Pat from a table in my database.  I want it to only display John and Steve.

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name");
$line = @mysql_fetch_array($result);
$users = $line[user];

echo "$users";
```

Comment: You should NEVER do `@mysql_query`!  It's nice to see SQL errors, so you can fix them.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the mysql extention at all anymore. You should be using mysqli or PDO.

Comment: You should read up on SQL before using it.  This is called a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 3):

`SELECT * FROM name WHERE [column_name] = 'john' OR [column_name] = 'Steve'`

Is that what you're looking for?  A few notes:

1. You'll need to replace `[column_name]` with the name of the actual column being compared, since that's not specified in your code above.
2. Try not to use `SELECT *` where possible.  It's generally better practice to select the actual column names.  Slightly less work on the database, doesn't break as easily when schema changes, etc.
3. This comparison is case-sensitive.

**UPDATE:** Correction, MySQL isn't case-sensitive.  So #3 above shouldn't be a concern in that environment.

Comment: @Rocket: You may be correct, I guess I'm not certain.  I don't have an instance in front of me to test.  It's at least something the developer should explicitly keep in mind, though.

Answer (score 2):

You need a WHERE clause in your SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE somecolumn=somevalue;
```

Answer (score 2):

For this odd example, you could change your query to:

```
select * from name where name in ('Steve','John')
```

or

```
select * from name where name <> 'Pat'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can filter by a list of matching names in the SQL thusly:

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE name IN ('John', 'Steve')
```

This assumes your table is called `name` and the column containing the user's name is also called `name`.

I have to wonder what you are trying to achieve here, is there some other useful information you are trying to get from the user record? Or should you be limiting the users returned based on some other criteria beyond their name?

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM name LIMIT 2");
```

Comment: MySQL does not guarantee order of rows in output, unless ORDER BY clause is used. So, this query may result in ANY 2 rows.

Comment: Yes but to be fair, the question isn't actually clear on what criteria he' after - if it happens to be the first 2 in the list, 2 specific entries, entries which don't contain the letter 'P' etc...